# Tool to get from one pattern to another?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, pattern-matching

Is there a tool that if you give it a set of strings that have been converted to another pattern, it can tell you how you can arrive at each pattern. As an example, I have the string:

`20G-34-41-01-00004.G-0020.01` and it has been converted to `20G344101    4G  2001`

and I want to know how to get from one to the other and vice versa.  There are more patterns, so that is why I was wondering if there was a tool for it.

Comment: The usual approach is to go with a _regular expression_, or _regex_. But you know what they say about that? At first you have a problem, then you use a regex, and now you have two problems.

Comment: How many patterns? Is there a pattern to the patterns?

Comment: Yes there is a pattern to a the patterns.

Comment: There's a lot of nuance to "getting a pattern" or ways "you can arrive at each pattern" -- if you're using a regular expression, you could use ".*" for your pattern and it'll work just fine. Getting a sensible pattern might be possible with a good diffing algorithm, but I can't think of an off-the-shelf API that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exclusively working with strings, it seems to me that creating a .ConvertTo(pattern) extension method is the way to go.

```
public enum ConversionTypesEnum
{
    LongDate,
    ShortDate,
    FatDate,
    SkinnyDate
}

public static string ConvertTo(this string stringtoConvert, ConversionTypesEnum type)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: My problem is the actual conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're asking about machine learning. There's brief discussion on [mathoverflow.com](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98013).

> In machine learning this is a common situation (given these finitely many cases of a function, "learn" the function on the rest of infinitely many cases). You should look at machine learning literature, as this is what you are doing. For example, you could ask, what is the simplest regular expression which matches the given test cases?
>
> ... Henning Fernau, [Algorithms for Learning Regular Expressions](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/%7Efernau/papers/Fer05c.pdf) (Extended Abstract).

Comment: The problem here is that `ApplyPattern` is what I am trying to find.

Comment: Sorry, @Xaisoft, I misunderstood your question. I thought you had a limited set of transformations and you were trying to choose which one had been applied. This question is much harder, and may be theoretically impossible without limiting the possible patterns in some way. I've replaced my answer.